# Component doesn't trigger functions

Tags: reactjs

```
render() {
    const { newRepo, loading, repositories } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
        <RepoForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={newRepo} />
          <SubmitButton loading={loading} />
        </RepoForm>
        <RepoList repositories={repositories} />
      </Container>
    );
```

```
export default function FormInput() {
  return <Container type="text" placeholder="Adicionar repositório" />;
}
```

My code doesn't activate the function onChange when I change the input. The two codes are in separate files. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you post `handleInputChange` function?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the detailed implementation of the `Container` component. Usually, you will need to pass down the even handler from parent to child as a prop.

```
// get the reference of the onChange prop
export default function FormInput({ onChange }) {
  // connect onChange function with the actual component that handles input
  return <Container type="text" onChange={onChange} placeholder="Adicionar repositório" />;
}
```

I hope it helps.